CompareIgnoreTime() in DateUtil
What is compareIgnoreTime() in DateUtil class?
compareIgnoreTime() is used in code, need to understand that why we are using this for two dates?
In code, CompareIgnoreTime() is used for DOB and current date and it's checking > Zero.

A moment is logically composed of two parts: a date and a time. If you compare a moment1 to a moment2, then if they happen to be on the same date, but at different times, then they are considered to be unequal.
So, your compareIgnoreTime seems to be comparing only the date parts and ignoring time differences, so if moment1 happened to be on a date at 2 PM and moment2 happened to be on a date at 3 PM, then they are still considered to be equal, despite the time differences.
